# Access aws IAM Policy JSON file programmatically .Net SDK

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to access the JSON File programmatically.

In the Management Console, you can find that right here
[image]

To be specific, not only do I want to access the managed, but also the custom policies.

Sorry, for not being familiar with the proper terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest familiarizing yourself with [the AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html).

You would get a policy object by calling the `AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient.GetPolicy()` method. This method requires the policy ARN. Next You would get the policy's versions by calling `AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient.ListPolicyVersions()`. Once you have both the policy ARN and the ID of the version you want (you probably just want to pull the ID of the latest version out of the versions list), then you would call `AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient.GetPolicyVersion()` to get the actual policy JSON document.

If you don't know the ARN for the policy, or you just want to loop through all policies, you would call the `AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient.ListPolicies()` method to get a list of all policies. You mentioned in your question that you want to retrieve both the customer managed and AWS managed policies, which this method does:

> "Lists all the managed policies that are available in your AWS
>   account, including your own customer-defined managed policies and all
>   AWS managed policies."

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realized that including the managed policies would be rather silly. Is there an easy way to exclude the managed policies from the list of policies I want to get? Also, I find the part of the doc concerning IAM rather confusing and lacking proper examples

Comment: To list only your own policies pass a `Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.ListPoliciesRequest` instance to the `ListPolicies()` method, with the `Scope` attribute set to `Amazon.IdentityManagement.PolicyScopeType.Local`.

Comment: Note that I'm not a .NET developer, I'm just reading and interpreting the docs for you. I agree that the AWS .NET SDK documentation is not very easy to read, but it appears to follow the standard .NET documentation format. I've used the Java, JavaScript and Python AWS SDKs and I've found them both cleaner and easier to use than what I'm seeing with the .NET SDK. However, this isn't the place to complain about the documentation, you should send feedback to Amazon if you want them to improve the docs.